# Is the centre of charge always within the centre of mass of an object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, mass, charge

What I am confused about is whether the charge of an object is concentrated within the centre of the mass itself, or does it change depending on the situation?

Comment: Imagine a proton and an electron separated by some distance. The charge of this system is not within its center of mass.

Comment: Physicists don’t define a center of charge because with both positive and negative charges it doesn’t make sense. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/why-isnt-there-a-centre-of-charge

Comment: Since the center of mass is a point, nothing can be within it. Are you asking whether the center of charge & the center of mass always coincide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charge and mass are independent properties of a body. The center of mass and charge of a body depend solely on the way the mass or charge is distributed about the body. If both are distributed in the same way, their centers will coincide.

Comment: What will affect the distribution of charge?

Comment: A rod for example may have a linear charge density, this will mean that the center will not be at the middle. Simply bringing a magnet close to a body will also disturb the distribution of charge.